# Javascript find method doesn't stop after first match

Tags: javascript, methods, find

my Problem is, that I want to extract a specific css class (grid-8 / col-4) via javascript.

If the desired class is the first or the only array element, the javascript function "find" returns undefined for the matching element, what doesn't make sense for me.
[find method specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

I can't find the mistake. Every console.log statement returns the expected value, except the "find" function.

Hopefully you can give me a hint!

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-8 layout">

    <div class="col-4 master">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var $layout = $(".layout");
    var $elem = $(".master");

    var layoutColumNumber = getNumberOfColums($layout, 'grid');
    var elementColumNumber = getNumberOfColums($elem, 'col');

    function getNumberOfColums(object, type){
        var classArray = getElementClassArray(object);
        var elementColWidth = null;

        switch(type){
            case 'grid':
            elementColWidth = classArray.find(gridClassPosition).split("-")[1];
            break;
            case 'col':
            elementColWidth = classArray.find(colClassPosition).split("-")[1];
            break;
        }
        return elementColWidth;
    }

    function getElementClassArray(object){
        return object.attr('class').split(' ');
    }

    function gridClassPosition(element, index, array){
        return (element.startsWith('grid-')) ? index : false;
    }

    function colClassPosition(element, index, array){
        return (element.startsWith('col-')) ? index : false;
    }

});
```

Comment: So `gridClassPosition()` returns an index, a number, or the booleans true or false, how would `Array.prototype.find` work with that, it's an array of classes, are any of these classes just a number, or even weirder, a boolean, if not, what do you expect to find ?

Comment: Also, you're complicating this beyond belief, why not just `$('.layout[class^="grid-"]').attr('class').replace('layout','').trim();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/snbnbfwx/

Comment: @adneo:  
the gridClassPosition() returns the index of the desired class in the array or any non true value. The way the specification explains it.
The classes in the array are css classes and marked as strings.

My expectation is to find the grid-* class to split it, so in the end I only have the number.

Comment: @adneo:
Thank you for your alternative example. That was my first way also, but in future I don't know which other classes the specific element will have, so I'm looking for a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is, that the index of the first element in an array is 0. And in JavaScript 0 is no true value. It's a false value.
That's why the find function returns 'undefined' as correctly described in the specification.

In this case the return value doesn't matter. So it's enough to return true if "find" reaches the desired element.

With a `console.log(classArray.find(colClassPosition))` you will see that you have the current element in the array, where in turn you can call on the split function.